# Can not umount NFS directory (ignored)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs4

I have a few servers that have NFS mounted directories.
I have shut down the service that is using them, and fuser -m doesnt show any other processes using any files there.

When i do "umount -at nfs" i dont get any error messages, but also nothing happens. The directories remain mounted, and seemingly in operational state.

If i add -v to umount it says that those directories are - ignored.
Also -f doesnt help anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those filesystems are actually using NFSv4, then the type should be `-t nfs4` instead of `-t nfs`. This is a kind of asymmetry, because those can be mounted using also the `-t nfs` option.

You can check this by using for example `df -T` which will display Type `nfs4` instead of `nfs`.

So try this:

```
umount -at nfs4
```

Explictly umount-ing a specific path without stating the mount type should also work of course.